# Structuring an object in python to direct '.' access to an attribute

Tags: python-3.x

I'm building an object in Python using Marshmallow schema - and I was hoping to make the experience more elegant for users.

So, if I have an object like the following (stripped down to simplify):

```
from dotmap import DotMap

class User:
    def __init__(self, name: str, kids: dict):
        self.name = name
        self.kids = DotMap(kids)
```

Then let's say I did the following:

```
steve = User('steve', {'sally': 8, 'harry': 6}
steve.sally = 9
steve.harry = 7
```

Basically, instead of that first '.' accessing attributes on User, it's redirected to the DotMap. Is this possible? I realize this would make things challenging, because it would mean that all attributes on User (e.g. `name`) could be hidden by having the same key in the DotMap.

Comment: It's a little unclear, do you only need to proxy *assignments* to attributes on the `User`, or do you need to translate reading of attributes too? That is, do you expect to be able to do `print(steve.sally)` and have it work?

Comment: @aronchick please give an example of what your trying to achieve as your final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I used Box (https://codecalamity.com/introducing-box-python-dictionaries-with-recursive-dot-notation-access/) to accomplish this.

I didn't want to actually hand anything to User, I just wanted to have a system for reading and writing to something that was instantiated FROM User, but then all information was maintained in the object. Sorry that wasn't more clear!